# What certificate do I need for Windows driver signing?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, certificate, driver, driver-signing

Drivers for recent (64-bit) version of Windows must be signed before they'll load.  Which certificate issuers can supply a certificate suitable for this?

Comment: I think this is a good question, badly written.  KMCS is now vital for getting device drivers to run on recent versions of Windows, and it's very difficult to unearth the details of how to do it and what you need to do it with.  Closing it as 'not related to software development in some way' implies to me that the closers have failed to understand the question at all.

Comment: @Will Dean, last time it's quite common when people close or downvote questions they aren't able to understand

Answer (score 8):

If you're talking about Kernel-Mode Driver Signing for 64-bit drivers, then your only two options are Verisign (Veri-expensive) and Globalsign (not quite so very-expensive).

I think everyone else on the list you can find at microsoft.com is now defunct, and as MS have not one scrap of interest in denting Verisign's excessive influence, they've not bother to add anyone else.

Even Thawte (part of Verisign) certs can't be used for KMCS, so don't get caught like that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they finally updated the CA list:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487315